# keep contents between one pattern to another pattern

Tags: python, regex

I want to parse html contents and keep the contents from A to B
ex:

```
some content1...
<!-- begin_here -->
some content2
<!-- end_here -->
some content3
```

will become

```
<!-- begin_here -->
some content2
<!-- end_here -->
```

Now, I use sed to do:

```
sed '/begin_here/,/end_here/!d' file.html > file2.html
```

However, I'd like to rewrite it using python for cross-platform purpose.
I am not very familiar to regex in python.
Could give me some hints to do this?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You don't really need to use regex for this. Iterating over the file should work as well if your delimiters are always the same.

Comment: @Blender oh yes, sounds workable,
I can readline and check to keep or ignore.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without regular expressions, like so:

```
add_next = False # Do not add lines
# Until you encounter the first "start_here", which sets it to True
with open("file1.html", "r") as in_file:
    with open("file2.html", "w") as out_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if "end_here" in line: # or line.startswith("end_here") for example
                add_next = False
            if add_next:
                out_file.write(line)
            if "begin_here" in line:
                add_next = True
```

Answer (score 2):

Use multiline regex

```
import re
pat = re.compile('''^<!-- begin_here -->.*?<!-- end_here -->$''', 
                 re.DOTALL + re.MULTILINE)

with open("file.txt") as f:
    print pat.findall(f.read())
```